# Type reduction infinite loop

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop, typechecking, type-families

My aim is to eliminate `()` from terms, like this:

```
(a, b)       -> (a, b)
((), b)      -> b
(a, ((), b)) -> (a, b)
...
```

And this is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Simplify where

import Data.Type.Bool
import Data.Type.Equality

type family Simplify x where
  Simplify (op () x) = Simplify x
  Simplify (op x ()) = Simplify x
  Simplify (op x y)  = If (x == Simplify x && y == Simplify y)
                          (op x y)
                          (Simplify (op (Simplify x) (Simplify y)))
  Simplify x         = x
```

However, trying it out:

```
:kind! Simplify (String, Int)
```

...leads to an infinite loop in the type checker. I'm thinking the `If` type family should be taking care of irreducible terms, but I'm obviously missing something. But what?

Comment: It seems you are assuming that type-level computation is lazy, hence that the second branch of the `If` won't be evaluated unless it is needed. I think that assumption is unwarranted.

Comment: And by the way: being polymorphic over `op` is probably wrong. For example, `Simplify (Either () Int)` probably should not reduce to `Int`.

Comment: What should the behaviour be on `(String, (), Int)`? Both solutions suggested so far reduce that to `Int`. I don't even know if it's possible to get `(String, Int)`.

Comment: @gallais: That's fine, terms can be (nested) tuples only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type family evaluation isn't lazy, so `If c t f` will evaluate all of `c`, `t`, and `f`.  (In fact, type family evaluation order isn't really defined at all right now.)  So it's no wonder you end up with an infinite loop – you always evaluate `Simplify (op (Simplify x) (Simplify y))`, even when that's `Simplify (op x y)`!

You can avoid this by splitting the recursion and the simplification apart, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Simplify where

import Data.Type.Bool
import Data.Type.Equality

type family Simplify1 x where
  Simplify1 (op () x) = x
  Simplify1 (op x ()) = x
  Simplify1 (op x y)  = op (Simplify1 x) (Simplify1 y)
  Simplify1 x         = x

type family SimplifyFix x x' where
  SimplifyFix x x  = x
  SimplifyFix x x' = SimplifyFix x' (Simplify1 x')

type Simplify x = SimplifyFix x (Simplify1 x)
```

The idea is:

1. `Simplify1` does one step of simplification.
2. `SimplifyFix` takes `x` and its one-step simplification `x'`, checks if they're equal, and if they aren't does another step of simplification (thus finding the fixed point of `Simplify1`).
3. `Simplify` just starts off the `SimplifyFix` chain with a call to `Simplify1`.

Since type family *pattern matching* is lazy, `SimplifyFix` correctly delays evaluation, preventing infinite loops.

And indeed:

```
*Simplify> :kind! Simplify (String, Int)
Simplify (String, Int) :: *
= (String, Int)

*Simplify> :kind! Simplify (String, ((), (Int, ())))
Simplify (String, ((), (Int, ()))) :: *
= ([Char], Int)
```

Comment: Wow, I was writing up an answer, too... and came up with *exactly* the same choice for second test case. For what it's worth, I think my answer is slightly simpler, though perhaps less generalizable: `Simplify1 ((), y) = y; Simplify1 (x, ()) = x; Simplify1 other = other; Simplify (x, y) = Simplify1 (Simplify x, Simplify y); Simplify other = other`.

Comment: @DanielWagner I mean, you have to nest the `()`s at least two deep for a real test, right? :-)  And it's nice to compare your solution!

Comment: Also, a fun bit of magic: `:kind! forall a. Simplify1 (a, ()) = a`. That takes some real cleverness, given that it has to notice the first two clauses of `Simplify1` will give the same answer!

Comment: @DanielWagner: … this baffles me.  I really don't feel like that should work at all!

Comment: @DanielWagner, it probably reuses some of the same-RHS logic used to check open type families. A bit unexpected, and I wonder just where it shouts "Surprise!" and breaks down, but definitely cool.

Comment: @DanielWagner Aren't the clauses always tried in-order, in _closed_ type families?

Comment: @chi: Yes, but usually type variables don't reduce at all, because we don't know if they'll unify with the patterns or not. E.g., given `type family F x where { F () = Bool ; F a = a }`, then `:kind! forall a. F a` gives `forall a. F a :: * = F a`, because in some sense it's waiting to see if `a` is equal to `()` or not. But apparently, if the RHS is the same in all cases, then it reduces somehow! E.g., given `type family G x where { G () = () ; G a = a }`, you indeed have `:kind! forall a. G a` producing `forall a. G a :: * = a`. So this is (to me) quite astonishing.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky Ah, I misread `Simplify1 ((), a) = a` and couldn't see the issue. Intriguing.

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky My guess is, whenever `F p = p' ; F q = q'`, compute the MGU `m` of `p,q` and check whether under that we have `p'[m]=q'[m]` syntactically. If so, add a third clause before the two stating `F p[m] = p'[m]`. The syntactic check could be smarter, of course -- this is a fragile heuristics, but I can't believe GHC can afford much more than this.

Comment: @chi What is the MGU of `(x,())` and `((),y)`? Is it not `x ~ (), y ~ ()`? If so, how does an extra clause `Simplify1 ((), ()) = ()` at the start help?

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd mention that given that the simplification has the structure of a fold, there is no need to build this complex solution involving a fixpoint which re-traverses the expression again and again.

This will do just fine:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Simplify where

type family Simplify x where
  Simplify (op a b) = Op op (Simplify a) (Simplify b)
  Simplify x        = x

type family Op op a b where
  Op op () b = b
  Op op a () = a
  Op op a b  = op a b
```